# Using ls command result in a loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops, ls

I want to use the result of ls command in a loop to check if for example the first line is a directory, second etc. 
For example I have this folder that contains one directory the script should display:

> 18_05_2018 is directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24tOL.png)

Comment: Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yours.

Comment: And please don't use unnecessary shouty text.

Comment: Do you only want to check for directories?

Comment: I'm so sorry I am a new user @LuisMuñoz

Comment: Hi @devius I am so sorry for being late.. yes that is my question but by using ls command in a loop however I solved it..Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file named is_file_or_directory.sh containing:

```
cd "$1" || echo "Please specify a path" && exit
for i in *; do
    if [[ -d $i ]]; then
        echo "$i is a directory"
    elif [[ -f $i ]]; then
        echo "$i is a file"
    else
        echo "$i is not valid"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Make that file executable with:

```
sudo chmod +x is_file_or_directory.sh
```

Run the script specifying as a parameter the path that you want to analyze:

```
./is_file_or_directory.sh /root/scripts/
```

Output:

```
jeeves ~/scripts/stack # ./is_file_or_dir.sh /root/scripts/
databe.py is a file
is_file_or_dir.sh is a file
mysql_flask.py is a file
test is a directory
```

Here's a more detailed explanation of what is happening under the hood. The variable $1 is, in Bash, the first parameter sent to the script. In our case it is the path where the script will perform its actions. Then we use the variable $i in the loop.

$i content will be every file / folder name in the path $1. With -d and -f we check if $i is a file or a folder.

Comment: `for file in $(ls)` is [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and the subject of [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). It's not a practice we should be teaching. Moreover, `ls $1` is missing quotes, so if the script were run as `./run-script-with "My Documents"`, it would first look for a directory `My`, then a second directory `Documents`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @CharlesDuffy, I am now correcting my code

Comment: thank you very mutch @Pitto and sorry for being late I had some exams

Comment: @Pitto, ...consider `cd "$1" || exit` -- without the quotes, `cd` into directory names without quotes will fail; without the `|| exit`, the code will continue to run in the wrong directory if the `cd` fails.

Comment: Nice addition, @CharlesDuffy!
I also took the freedom to inform the user about what happened.
Thanks for the suggestions :)